# Authentication fail using LDAP Login Module for Teiid VDB Data Virtualization

Tags: ldap, redhat, teiid, data-virtualization, redhat-datavirt

we are currently running into issues when configuring LDAP authentication for a deployed VDB, we would like to enter our active directory username and password when authenticating.

We have successful configured LDAP authentication for admin console, but running into errors during server start up.

I have been able to successfully configure authentication for the admin console at hostname:9990. I have done so by with the following changes to Standalone.xml we can provide our active directory user/pass and log in to the admin console.

Below are defined security domain which we are running into issues. And a security realm which is working.

This is the error we are receiving

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception during createSubject() for java:/refresh: PBOX000016: Access denied: authentication failed: java.lang.SecurityException: PBOX000016: Access denied: authentication failed
    at org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossSecuritySubjectFactory.createSubject(JBossSecuritySubjectFactory.java:84)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer$1.run(AbstractDsDeployer.java:1086)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer$1.run(AbstractDsDeployer.java:1081)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer.createSubject(AbstractDsDeployer.java:1080)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer.deployDataSource(AbstractDsDeployer.java:600)
    at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractDsDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractDsDeployer.java:282)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService$AS7DataSourceDeployer.deploy(AbstractDataSourceService.java:318)
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceService.start(AbstractDataSourceService.java:122)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_121]
```

This is the security realm which is working when authenticating for the admin panel

```
<security-realm name="ldap-security-realm">
<authentication>
    <ldap connection="ldap-connection" base-dn="dc=main">
         <advanced-filter filter="(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0}))"/>
     </ldap>
 </authentication>
</security-realm>

<outbound-connections>
   <ldap name="ldap-connection" url="ldap://hostname:389" search dn="adminusername" search-credential="adminpassword"/>
</outbound-connections>
```

This is the security domain which we are trying to enable authentication for a deployed VDB

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/refresh" pool-name="refresh" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:teiid:refresh@mm://hostname:31000</connection-url>
    <driver>teiid</driver>
    <security>
      <security-domain>test_ldap_security_domain</security-domain>
    </security>
</datasource>

<security-domain name="test_ldap_security_domain">
    <authentication>
         <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="sufficient">
             <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://hostname:389" />
             <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" />
             <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple" />
             <module-option name="bindDN" value="adminusername" />
             <module-option name="bindCredential" value="adminpassword" />
             <module-option name="distinguishedNameAttribute" value="sAMAccountName" />
             <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})" />  
             <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="dc=main" />
             </login-module>
     </authentication>
</security-domain>

<transport name="odata">
    <authentication security-domain="test_ldap_security_domain"/>
</transport>
<transport name="jdbc" socket-binding="teiid-jdbc" protocol="teiid">
    <authentication security-domain="test_ldap_security_domain"/>
</transport>
<transport name="odbc" socket-binding="teiid-odbc" protocol="pg">
    <authentication security-domain="test_ldap_security_domain"/>
    <ssl mode="disabled"/>
</transport>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data source configuration by default during the startup tries to create a minimum number of connections. Since data source is secured based on user credentials and there is no active user during the startup it fails.

Change the data source configuration not to create any connections during the startup.

```html
<pool>
    <prefill>false</prefill>
</pool>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I am getting the same error. This is the configuration for the datasource now.
`<datasource jndi-name="java:/refresh" pool-name="refresh" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:teiid:refresh@mm://hostname:31000</connection-url>
        <driver>teiid</driver>
       <pool>
        <prefill>false</prefill>
      </pool>
    <security>
     <security-domain>test_ldap_security_domain</security-domain>
   </security>
</datasource>`

Comment: Also note that you can NOT use native metadata fetching, i.e. in your VDB's for this LDAP source, you can not dynamically ask to fetch metadata. Your LDAP model must contain all the necessary metadata for that model. When there is no metadata, during that startup, Teiid will try to create a connection and fetch metadata directly from the source. We can't have that situation here.